# File Storage is not working in my Laravel project

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6

I have created the symbolic link in Laravel project. But this `Storage::disk` isn't printing the image. Only the background thumbnail is printed. Data is stored in my table and storage path. But it does not show any image in my view page.? what is happening now. Did I make a mistake? Please check the image src line.

My table fields are:

```
logo_id
company_name
company_avatar
created_at
updated_at
```

This is my blade file image tag code

```php
<img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($data->company_avatar) }}" alt="User profile picture">
```

**Controller**

```php
class LogoController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = Tbl_logo::all();

        return view('admin.companylogo.index', compact('data'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $data = Tbl_logo::all();

        return view('admin.companylogo.create', compact('data'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new Tbl_logo();
        if ($request->hasFile('company_avatar')) {
            $imageName = $request->company_avatar->store('public');
        }
        $data->company_name = $request->company_name;
        $data->company_avatar = $imageName;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('admin/logo')->with('successfully created or uploaded image');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = Tbl_logo::find($id);

        return view('admin.companylogo.edit', compact('data'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = Tbl_logo::find($id);
        if ($request->hasFile('company_avatar')) {
            $imageName = $request->company_avatar->store('public');
        }
        $data->company_name = $request->company_name;
        $data->company_avatar = $imageName;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('admin/logo');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $data = Tbl_logo::find($id);
        $data->delete();

        return redirect('admin/logo')->with('success', 'Deleted Successfully...!');
    }
}
```